# ArcGIS Javascript API Editing - Create Feature from Geometry Object

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm interested in passing a geometry object with certain attributes to an exposed feature class for committed edits. Essentially, I want to manually create a new feature without the template pane or editor widget. The geometry and attributes are both pre-defined, and the user just needs to select one pair from a group and push an "Add to Geodatabase" button.

I'm reading through the documentation and I can't see a clear way to do this. I see that if I don't want the pane or widget, then I need to use a geometry service, but I don't see a "create feature" method, or something that accepts a geometry object or attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you seen [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_feature_creation.html) sample?

in general, whether you use the TemplatePicker or not, the approach you should take is the same.  That is to instantiate a [Graphic](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html) object using your geometry and attributes and pass the graphic within FeatureLayer.[applyEdits()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#applyedits).

depending on the argument position of the graphic, this method allows adding new features, editing existing feature geometry or attributes and deleting as well.

Comment: Thanks John, this is exactly what was needed. I think I breezed over this sample because it included the template picker, but I see that's not a vital part of the process.